# Boot image header fields are invalid

Tags: fastboot, boot

I want to install TWRP on Redmi 5 (Rosy), during installation everything works normally. But when I want to boot into TWRP,

```
fastboot boot TWRP.img
```

a failure message appears on the ADB command line.

```
FAILED (remote: bootimage header fields are invalid)
```

Previously I was on the EU MIUI Custom ROM. All happened after I tried to flash the MIUI 11 Global firmware

Comment: So you are trying to boot the [`twrp-3.5.2_9-0-rosy.img`](https://dl.twrp.me/rosy/twrp-3.5.2_9-0-rosy.img.html)? Have you checked the SHA256 hash that is also provided on that page to make sure the download is not corrupt (or alternatively verify the PGP signature)?

Comment: try this one [twrp-3.5.2_10_r1-rosy.img](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-10-rosy-twrp-recovery-3-5-2-r1-unofficial.4209233)

Comment: Thanks, all is done. I have to install TWRP base android 9/10. Maybe the boot image header on my phone is stuck in the boot image header for Android 9/10. How do I change back to the original version?

Comment: don't understand